# WPF MVVM : Add item to ObservableList + DB

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a model "Company" with "name, email, address", so I am planning to create a view with listbox to display all the companies for Database and a button to add new company(with a popup), the new company should be added to the list and to db.
I am confused if I have to create 2 ViewModels (one for all Companies and the other for add new company) since I have 2 views.

so my question is what is the best approach to create a popup window for adding new company, and should I create 1 or 2 viewmodels ?

Comment: you can create two view models. after all that's what view model is for. it's a model for a view.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a rule to have a ViewModel to the new popup window. You can choose different approaches.

Consider that one Panel in your main view is like a popup window. The difference can be way the user interacts with it.

In this case you can bind your controls of the popup window to the viewmodel properties and commands.

Comment: Thanks, but  I noticed in many examples that we use UserControl instead of Window so that we can navigate between views, I want to create "Add item" view which should be a popup (or window) ,I didn't find any way to navigate to window and creating (<popup>) makes xaml file smell.

Comment: It's a very good point. You can think about navigating to a page and opening a popup window as the same pattern. In both situations you will need to perform a View behavior. Yet you can think that both are navigation. Navigate to a page, navigate to a popup. Implementing them as navigation, you need different viewmodels for each new page, popup, etc. My suggestion is to thread the popup that uses the same DataContext of the Main view. Each approach has pros and cons. What do you prefer in this case? Hope it helps